# Designing a caching layer in front of a DB with minimal number of queries

Tags: database, algorithm, asynchronous, caching, ehcache

I have multiple jobs that work on some key. The jobs are ran asynchronously and are written to some write-behind cache. Conceptually it looks like this:

```
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| key |   job1    |   job2   |   job3   |   resolution   |
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+----------------+
| 123 | job1_res  | job2_res | job3_res | resolution_val |
+-----+-----------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

The key concept is that I don't know in advance how many jobs are running. Instead, when it's time to write the record we add our "resolution" (based on the current job results we've got) and write all values to the DB (MongoDB if that's matter)

I also have a `load()` function that runs in case of a cache-miss. What it does is to fetch the record from the database, or creating a new (and empty) one if the record wasn't found.

Now, **there's a time window where the record isn't in the cache nor in the database**. In that time, a "slow worker" might write its result, and unluckily the `load()` function will create a new record.

When evacuated from the cache, the record will look like this:

```
+-----+----------+-------------------------------+
| key |   job4   |         resolution            |
+-----+----------+-------------------------------+
| 123 | job4_val | resolution_based_only_on_job4 |
+-----+----------+-------------------------------+
```

**I can think of two ways to control this problem:**

1. Configure the write-behind mechanism so it will wait for all jobs to complete (i.e. give sufficient amount of time)
2. On write event, first query the DB for the record and merge results.

**Problems with current solutions:**

1. Hard to calibrate
2. Demands an extra query for write operation

What's the most natural solution to my problem?

Do I have to implement solution #2 in order to guarantee a resolution on all job results?

**EDIT:**
Theoretically speaking, I think that even after implementing solution #2 it doesn't give us the guarantee that the resolution will be based on all job results.

**EDIT2:**
If the write-behind mechanism guarantees order of operations then solution #2 is ok. This can be achieved by limiting the write-behind to one thread.

Comment: 1. How about adding a flag that indicates a previous write to the DB based on a resolution? The DB would only be queried upon resolution if this flag was set. The flag's default value would be 'false', ie. upon the first creation of a record for a given key. 2. Would an incremental resolution be feasible? The cache would contain the most recent resolution result and be updated to incorporate new job results before each db write.

Comment: 1. Flag can't achieve much (IMHO) as a record can be evacuated from the cache and for a short period of time it wouldn't be in the cache nor in the database. Sure, if you configure your cache correctly it can be a very rare event, but theoretically speaking, it can happen.

Comment: A `CacheWriter` should be atomic with the cache operation, e.g. removal. Then the load won't race with an eviction. Not sure if Ehcache implements it that way, though. That incurs penalty of the db write on the cache write lock, which may not always be okay. Another option is to side-load by evicting into a output map, which the loader can fetch from, and draining that map asynchronously. Then you are coordinating but a bit ad hoc.

Comment: @BenManes, do you think `CacheWriter` should be atomic with respect to `get` operations as well?

Comment: Yes if a loading get (e.g. when calling a CacheLoader) and no if a lookup (e.g. present). A read should be lock free on a hit, while a miss should be under a lock and be atomic.